# Sliding Menu in Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nsscrollview

How can I make a sliding menu like (as an example) Sparrow's main email menu?

In the case of Sparrow:

It's a column of buttons that essentially slide to reveal a NSScrollView (with custom NSTableView?) with various folders inside (inbox, sent, etc). Clicking on a different account causes that account to slide up to the top and reveals the various folders inside.

How could I go about doing a menu similar to this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some fairly cool Apple sample code here to deal with table views and animation (uses stuff that is generally only available as of Mac OS X 10.7 however):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AnimatedTableView/Listings/ATPopupWindow_m.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008863-ATPopupWindow_m-DontLinkElementID_26

Also, for basic window resize animation you can use the `setFrame:display:animate:` method of `NSWindow`.